# sieve of erastothenes - initialize big bit array in C

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So I'm trying to implement the sieve of Erastothenes using a bit array in C.
I've tried manually setting the bits using

```
    int x;
    int i;

    x = x | (1 << i);    // Set bit position i in x
```

However, I realized this will be too much iterations when I'm doing 10,000 iterations. If I use a 32-bit `unsigned int` array for my bit array, how do I initialize all 32 bits at once?

I tried setting

```
unsigned int[] arr = { [0-100000] = 1 };
```

that obviously didn't work.

Comment: A 32-bit unsigned int with all of its bits set has the value…?

Comment: Regardless of anything else, `unsigned int[] arr` is invalid syntax (and seems to lead to at least one incorrect answer below from copy-and-paste).

Comment: Check out the duplicate of examples how to _initialize_ an array to a single value, rather than to run-time assign it with `memset`, which is _not_ initialization. To set all bits to 1, use `~0u`.

Comment: Complete example using the code from the duplicate: https://godbolt.org/z/Gcdz8qf73

Answer (score 2):

> If I use a 32bit unsigned int array for my bit array, how do I initialize all 32 bits at once?

The below initializes all 10,000 elements of the array `arr_not[]` to zero.

```
uint32_t arr_not[10000]  = { 0 };
```

To use in OP's code, reverse the sense of a cleared bit to mean 1 in the  original algorithm.

Standard C does not well support a way to initialize all the bits to 1 for such a large array.

---

Otherwise simply code as below to assign all the bits of `arr[]` to 1.

```
uint32_t arr[10000];
memset(arr, UCHAR_MAX, sizeof arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of the 32bit unsigned int to 4294967295 or, if the number is a signed 32bit int set it to -1

11111111111111111111111111111111 <- 32 1's I used this site to convert it to decimal.
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

For an `unsigned` value with all bits set, use `~0U`.
  For type like `uintmax_t`, use something like `~(uintmax_t)0`

Comment: `~UINTMAX_C(0)` from `<stdint.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to use `memset`:

```
unsigned int arr[100000];
memset(arr, 0xff, sizeof arr);
```